# From Json to Data frame or csv in R

Tags: json, r

I'm trying to convert this json file with fromJSON in R and I cant

```
{"data":[
{"id_str": "972985896999014403", "created_at": "Mon Mar 12 00:01:29 +0000 2018", "text": "One week later, and Ryan Seacrest\u2019s weird #Oscars night is still with ", "name": "680 CJOB", "screen_name": "680CJOB"}}, ........
```

my code:

```
json_data<-fromJSON(file="input.json")
Error in fromJSON(file = "input.json") : 
  argument "txt" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have the name of the argument to `fromJSON` wrong. It should be `txt` or, because it is the first one just left unnamed:

```
json_data <- fromJSON(txt = "input.json")

# also works
json_data <- fromJSON("input.json")
```

Comment: json_data<-fromJSON(txt="BF4sucks_crawled.json")
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage
          ", "screen_name": "680CJOB"}},  {"id_str": "9729858601898024
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: The same with the second one

Comment: I did it!! Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       BF4sucks_crawled.json
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: I am also getting same error. Any reason / solution?

Comment: Are you sure your json is formatted correctly? You can check if it's valid using a site like this: https://jsonlint.com/